# Unique path in an undirected graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

To tell whether there is a path between two vertices or not is efficient, such as DFS or BFS, it will be done within O(V+E). How about deciding whether there are more than one paths between two given vertices? The path should be simple path, i.e with no repeated vertex. It is not necessarily the shortest path. Will it be done with O(V+E)? Just tell the existence, no need to give the exact path.

Comment: What do you mean by 2nd path? Does the second path share any V or E with the first?

Comment: @dfb They can share some V or E. We can present the simply path by the ordered sequence of edges, they should be different in at least one edge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach 1:**

Do a regular BFS from the source node, but continue until you've explored the entire graph, not just until you've found the target.

This should give you a path from the source to the target.

If you get multiple paths, these will be paths that have no vertices apart from the source and target in common (and, if this happens, you can stop here).

Now do another search from the source node.

If we're currently on a node in the path found above, explore all neighbours (recursively, in a DFS fashion) except the one following that node in the path above. After that explore that node.

Some pseudo-code to explain better:

```
path = bfs(source, target)

dfs(n)
  visited[n] = true
  if path.contains(n)
    next = path[path.indexOf(n) + 1]   // next node in path after n
    for each neighbour n2 of n
      if n2 != next and !visited[n2]
        if path.contains(n2)
          found multiple paths
        dfs(n2)
    dfs(next)
  else
    for each neighbour n2 of n
      if path.contains(n2)
        found multiple paths
      dfs(n2)
```

The running time should still be `O(|V| + |E|)`.

**Approach 2:**

(not a good approach, just look at the running time - perhaps someone sees an efficient variation)

Do a BFS from the source node with the following modification:

Continue until you've explored the entire graph, not just until you've found the target.

If you encounter an already visited node that's not on the same path (i.e. would form a cycle) <sup>[1]</sup>, rather than simply skipping it, instead set a flag on that node.

When you've finished doing the BFS, go through the found path and if any nodes have their flag set, we know that there exists multiple paths.

The running time should still be `O(|V||E|)`.

[1]: Checking whether a node is on the same path is not exactly easy to do efficiently. Basically you want a set of nodes.

One option is a literal set of nodes - the problem here is that you have to copy it at each step, which is really expensive.

Building on this, a bitset of nodes would be more efficient. For 1000 nodes, we only take 1000 bits to store a path. For really sparse graphs (graphs with few edges), this is actually worse than a literal set.

Another option is to assign a unique prime number to each node. When doing the BFS, maintain a product of all nodes for each path. To check whether an already visited node is on the same path, simply check if the product is divisible by the node's value.

Comment: For the BFS procedure, could one vertex be pushed into the stack for many times, if yes, the running time would not be O(V+E). It don't think the way to check is practicable. Suppose there are thousands of vertices, the product of the first thousand primes is really big, it will be linear with the number of vertices to  calculate this product as well as much memory.

Comment: @notbad One vertex can't be pushed onto the stack many times, but yeah, I guess this won't be too efficient. I edited my answer with a completely different approach.

Answer (score 0):

If all vertices minus the source and destination are forbidden, you can remove them and try to find another path.  Same thing with edges.  If they can share all but one vertex/edge, you can try removing each in the path in time `O(V(V+E))` or simply continue the DFS and count the number of paths.

Comment: Continuing the DFS will not accurately find the number of paths, because it will not find paths that pass through an already discovered path without modification.

Comment: @Andrey - depends on your definition of path.  If they only need to differ by a single edge this works fine.

Comment: I guess it depends on what you mean by "count the number of paths."  Once a path has been found, it is not enough to continue the DFS algorithm as it is usually written, where the condition being checked is that you are adjacent to the target vertex.  You need to also check against adjacency to an already-discovered path, because the DFS recursion condition will not send you down it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in one go, using *arbitrary* traversal algorithm.

You start the traversal in the vertex `s`.
Whenever you visit a new vertex, you mark it as visited, note the back-edge and continue with the traversal as usual.

When you visit a vertex that has been marked as visited, you mark it as twice-visited and return from the traversal branch.

You continue the traversal even after the `t` is visited.
After the traversal is over, you start in `t` and reconstruct the path using the noted back-edges in every vertex, same way you would do when finding a path from `s` to `t`.

When you find at least one twice-visited vertex `v` on this path, then since there are at least two paths from `s` to `v`, there are also at least two paths from `s` to `t`.

If there are only once-visited vertices on the path, there is also only one path from `s` to `t`.

Such algorithm has a running time `O(|E|)`.